# How to Create a DataFrame with Loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, fuzzy-logic

```
data = {'col1':['Country', 'State', 'City', 'park' ,'avenue'],
       'col2':['County','stats','PARK','Avenue', 'cities']}



    col1     col2
0   Country   County
1   State     stats
2   City      PARK
3   park      Avenue
4   avenue    cities
```

i was trying to match name of two columns with fuzzy wuzzy technique and order them by score.

output:

```
col1    col2   score  order
0 Country County  92     1
1 Country stats   31     2
2 Country PARK    18     3
3 Country Avenue  17     4
4 Country cities  16     5
5 State   County  80     1
6 State   stats   36     2
7 State   PARK    22     3
8 State   Avenue  18     4
9 State   cities  16     5
.....
```

what i did:

'''

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

    for i in df.col1:
        for j in df.col2:
            print(i,j,fuzz.token_set_ratio(i, j))
```

'''

i got stuck here..

Answer (score 3):

Let us do

```
df['score']=df.apply(lambda x : fuzz.ratio(x['col1'],x['col2']),1)
df['score']
0    92
1    60
2     0
3     0
4    17
dtype: int64
```

Then

```
df['order']=(-df['score']).groupby(df['col1']).rank(method='first')
```